# How to export (dest) in multiple folder

Tags: gulp

I have this Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('haml', function(){
  log('Compiling Haml to Html!');

  var hamlConfig = [
    './src/views/products/bancos/*.haml',
    './src/views/products/oferta/*.haml'
  ]

  return gulp
    .src(hamlConfig)
    .pipe($.rubyHaml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
  );
});
```

**Issue:**

When I do `gulp haml` in my terminal, it compiles haml files into html and export them into the `dist` folder.

**Approach**

What I'm trying to approach is when I use my task I want to export all these files in their respective folders:

example:

`./src/views/products/bancos/*.haml` into `./dist/bancos/*.html`

and

`./src/views/products/oferta/*.haml` into `./dist/oferta/*.html`

I tryed passing and array in `dest` function but it didn't work that easy.

Comment: Fwiw, unless there's some specific reason to not do this, you can tighten up your code by removing the `var hamlConfig` part and just saying `.src(['./src/views/products/bancos/*.haml', './src/views/products/oferta/*.haml'])` (or maybe even just `.src('./src/view/products/**/*.haml')` depending on your project)

Comment: Wow, you were right, I was looking for a similar question for over 30 minutes with no results, thanks, this solved my issue. Thanks!.